# Sonar Adding a new project

Tags: java, php, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am trying to add a new project into `sonar`. When running sonar runner, I'm getting the following error, Can anyone please help me on this.

`sonar-runner`

```
Runner configuration file: /opt/lampp/htdocs/typo3/sonar-runner-1/conf/sonar-
runner.properties
Project configuration file: /opt/lampp/htdocs/typo3/sonar-project.properties
Runner version: 2.0
Java version: 1.6.0_24, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
OS name: "Linux", version: "2.6.38-8-generic", arch: "i386"
Default locale: "en_IN", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
Server: http://localhost:9000
Work directory: /opt/lampp/htdocs/typo3/.sonar
Total time: 1:00.153s
Final Memory: 0M/30M
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request server 
version
    at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.getServerVersion(Bootstrapper.java:73)
    at org.sonar.runner.Runner.checkSonarVersion(Runner.java:220)
    at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:15
at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:84)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:56)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(Unknown Source)
at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.remoteContent(Bootstrapper.java:125)
at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.getServerVersion(Bootstrapper.java:71)
... 4 more

XXXXXXXXX:/opt/lampp/htdocs/typo3$ `
```

Answer (score 3):

OK I found the fix by myself , My sonar was working in a port 9005 so i have set url sonar.properties files.

Answer (score 2):

The message "Fail to request server" explicitly states that this is something related to the Sonar server. Either it is not available (it might be down), or your configuration is not correct.